# WM6.5 - C# - Check if Start Menu is Visible

Tags: api, windows-mobile, startmenu

[image]

Hi guys,

I'm developing an Windows Mobile 6.5 start menu replacement called [JWMD Stuick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=681443). Currently, I'm able to detect if the Start Menu is created or destroyed by checking GetWindowLong() API.. Though this does not guarantee if Start Menu is visible or not because other cooked ROM was even if the Start Menu is closed or an app was executed from Start Menu -- the Start Menu GWL still has value.

Do guys have better ways or ideas how to check if Start Menu is Visible?

Thanks.

Comment: checking ForegroundWindow API did not work too..